# Remove namespace string via Attribute or Regex from XML

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have created an XML file, however one of the repeating nodes is adding a namespace reference (xmlns:kk="kk") and I cant seem to remove it. Only adds to first element/node. When I remove it by hand the XML file validates against XSD.

I have tried removing it when the xml attribute is created and after with Regex.

Creating XML

```
XmlDocument doc
 =doc.Load(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["doctemploc"]);
    XmlElement Blaett = doc.CreateElement("kk:Blaett","kk");
    XmlAttribute numbber = doc.CreateAttribute("number");
    Blaett.Attributes.Append(numbber);
```

Have tried

```
XmlElement Blaett = doc.CreateElement("Blaett");

nummer.RemoveAttribute("xmlns:kk");
nummer.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove()
nummer.Attributes("xmlns").Remove();
```

And after the XML file is created

```
public static class XMLExtensions
{
    public static void RemoveNamespace(this XmlDocument document, string 
@namespace) =>
        document.InnerXml = Regex.Replace(
            document.InnerXml,
            $@"((?<=\</|\<){@namespace}:|xmlns:{@namespace}=""[^""]+"")", 
            "");
}
```

This removes to much all KK references just need xmlns:kk="kk" removed

Comment: The repeating line in the xml file looks like this   xmlns:kk="kk" from line <Blaett numbber="311" xmlns:kk="kk">

Comment: Can you add your XML file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of pain, instead of KK I added the url to namespace

```
  namespace1 = "http://xmls.site.se/section/3.1";
  XmlElement Blaett = doc.CreateElement("kk:Blaett"," namespace1);
```

I did have to add this to every XmlElement however it removed the issue and in fact removed the xmlns:kk="kk".

Validated against XSD... happy days